# login and registration page not jump to the dashboard after registration and login proces

Tags: laravel-8, admin

I was having some errors and I have solved it.
those errors are:
1- ErrorException in `_slider.blade.php`
Attempt to read property "sliders" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _slider.blade.php)
I have changed the code from:

```
@if($company->sliders == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

to

```
@if($company && $company->sliders == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

2- ErrorException in `_tracking.blade.php`
Attempt to read property "tracking" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _tracking.blade.php)
I have changed the code from:

```
@if($company->tracking == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

to

```
@if($company && $company->tracking == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

3- ErrorException in `_about.blade.php`
Attempt to read property "about_us" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _about.blade.php)
I have changed the code from:

```
@if($company->about_us == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

to

```
@if($company && $company->about_us == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

4- ErrorException in `_our_branches.blade.php`
Attempt to read property "branches" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _our_branches.blade.php)
I have changed the code from:

```
@if($company->branches == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

to

```
@if($company && $company->branches == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

5- ErrorException in `_services.blade.php`
Attempt to read property "services" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _services.blade.php)
I have changed the code from:

```
@if($company->services == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

to

```
@if($company && $company->services == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

6- ErrorException in `_partners.blade.php`
Attempt to read property "partners" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _partners.blade.php)
I have changed the code from:

```
@if($company->partners == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

to

```
@if($company && $company->partners == 'on')
My code here
@endif
```

7- Error Call to a member in `app.blade.php`
Call to a member function getTranslation() on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ app.blade.php)
I have changed all `$company->` code to `$company && $company->`

8- ErrorException in `_header.blade.php`
Attempt to read property "sliders" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _header.blade.php)
I have changed all `$company->` code to `$company && $company->`

9- ErrorException in `_footer.blade.php`
Attempt to read property " " on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ _footer.blade.php)
I have changed all `$company->` code to `$company && $company->`

after resolving all these errors finally I'm on the main page [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvUO4.png)
But my problem is:
1- When I am on a registration page, I fill out the data, and when I press Create Account, there is no response. Rather, the same page is updated and it does not jump to the Dashboard page.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUhDO.jpg).

2- When I click on the login page link, I am directed to the login page, but when I fill out the login data and click on login, there is no response. Rather, the same page is updated and it does not jump to the Dashboard page. [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SoSD.jpg)

here is my `web.php` code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath']
    ], function(){

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Website\WelcomeController::class , 'index'])->name('welcome');

    Route::post('/getShipmentDetails', [\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ShipmentController::class , 'getShipmentDetails'])->name('getShipmentDetails');

});
```

I tried to activate the dashboard but was unable to do so.